# jqPlot / partial view jQuery slider/carousel MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I have jqPlot charts that are displayed in divs contained in partial views. Is there any way to create a carousel or slider using the divs/rendered charts? All the jQuery sliders I find want to work with li elements containing jpg/png - Is there anything that could carousel partial views containing my chart divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/ ? I have used it in the past to achieve something similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can maybe inspect following link : [http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/hiddenPlotsInTabs.html](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/hiddenPlotsInTabs.html).

Comment: coda slider was perfect for what I needed - many thanks torm! thanks also for the tab link Anthony